# Does the cucumber-js parallel functionality reuse nodes

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

Does anybody have any documentation on the parallel functionality in cucumber-js? I am currently testing software with a singleton design pattern and I am running into some issues with what looks like cucumber-js reusing nodes.

For example, in each test, I will be setting a cookie for a request.

When I have 8 tests and I run 8 parallel slaves all my tests pass as they are logging in with the correct user

When I have 8 tests and I run 4 parallel slaves I noticed that some cookies are being reused which leads me to believe that node containers are being reused. Has anybody got info on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after digging into this a little deeper the fact that you can name the slaves as seen in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#parallel tells me that these slaves are not dynamically spun up or tore down. This means that slaves are being reused.

What I recommend doing is creating a method in your before hooks to clean the state of the node before starting each test.

More info on how the parallel functionality works can be found in this PR https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/1018/files